# How to make EditText not focused when creating Activity

Tags: java, android, focus, android-edittext

I've read the other questions discussing this, and all of them work for my layouts, **except** for the very first one created.

At the moment, this is at the top of my `onCreate` method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

^ That makes it so at least the keyboard doesn't pop up on startup, but the `EditText` is still focused on.

This is the `XML` for my `EditText`:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changePass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="30" >
</EditText>
```

This is what it looks like when I bring up my activity:

[image]

The problem is that with some phones, when an `EditText` is focused like this, they can't write in it. I want it to **not** focus.

What I've done works for the next layouts brought up in that it the `EditTexts` are not focused on and would look more like this:

[image]

Notice that it's the same layout, though. This is the screen after the user has been brought back to this screen, which would indicate nothing wrong with the `XML` because this is the same `XML`, but the problem is that the `EditText` is only focused on when the activity is created.

I've done research and all of the other questions don't help me with this (they did however help the keyboard not show up, thankfully). How can I make it so the `EditText` on startup will look like the second screenshot, rather than the first?

Comment: Have you tried `android:focusable="false"` in `EditText` ?

Comment: @PratikButani that makes it so it can never be focused on, though.

Comment: Adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on my parent layout works for me.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can set property of Layout like `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

**Example:**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/changePass"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="30" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

May this one helpful ;)

Answer (score 19):

XML code:

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changePass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="30" >
</EditText>
```

Java code:

```
EditText edPwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
edtPwd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

> set focusable false in xml and set it true via the code

Comment: Good solution ... the answer marked correct results in the IME option `actionNext` failing completely.

Comment: I tried it first it didn't work, my bad I was testing on emulator with no touch screen, On real device its working like a charm, Thanks @Meher

Answer (score 12):

In your main_layout
add this 2 lines:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"> *YOUR LAYOUT CODE* </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Edit Text is not focused but the keyboard is visible.

Answer (score 3):

the best solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45139132/3172843

the **correct and simple** solution is to setFocusable false  and **setFocusableInTouchMode true** . so the EditText gain focus only when user touch that EditText

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in onCreate()

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or in onCreateView()

```
 getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I'm trying to open Editext after selection item of Spinner, so on that time not able to open keyboard & write down the values in Edit text, but I resolved my issue with this code.

> android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
> android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/titleName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_your_full_name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

XML Code

```
<EditText 
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:focusable="false"
    />
```

Java Code in onClickListerner

```
 mEdtEnterPhoneNumber.setFocusable(true);
    mEdtEnterPhoneNumber.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `android:focusable="false"` to disable it, but if that does not work for some reason, then you can simply put a `LinearLayout` and it will take the focus without disrupting your layout.

NOTE: Eclipse will give you an error saying that your `LinearLayout` is useless because it has no contents. You should be able to disregard it with no problems.

For example:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changePass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="30" >
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  do this programmatically. use `editText.setEnabled(false)` in  your `onStart()` method of your activity (not in onCreate() - because this is some method for initializing GUI  components)

Comment: This would completely disable the EditText, which is not what is needed. I'm not sure (because I haven't tested), but I don't think disabling and then re-enabling would work either.

Unless there's something I'm missing, make sure  you understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

add this line in the activity tag of the Manifest.xml file.when you click on the EditText the keyboard gets into focus.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

in the activity tag of the Manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

1) Its the simplest,open the manifest and put the following code between the activity tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

2) Put this attributes in the parent layout

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Manifest , copy and paste the beneath code.**

```
 <activity
   android:name=".LoginActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/changePassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Change Password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/accountPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/changePassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/changePassword" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changePassword" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That's one long wall of xml text... for the sake of future visitors, can you please [edit] and explain what does what?

Answer (score -7):

use  `android:focusable="false"`  for focusing disable

```xml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/changePass"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLength="30"
 android:focusable="false" >

</EditText>
```

Comment: it works, but that makes it so it can never be focused on, even after touching.

Comment: you can use event listener when you need to make it focusable

Comment: edit your answer to have that, and I'll vote you up. Someone already answered with what you said, though.