# How to change Auto Focus on EditText in Java Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext, focus

I call the function to open the dialog. Dialog boxes have two `EditText`. When I open the dialog box, the keyboard automatically pops up. How can I disable this behavior? I only need to open the keyboard when the `EditText` receives a touch event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can stop EditText auto-focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732545/can-stop-edittext-auto-focus)

Comment: Check these links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732545/can-stop-edittext-auto-focus

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295802/how-to-make-edittext-not-focused-when-creating-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your onCreate() method

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

If you want all your activity use soft keyboard use this in your manifest file for your all activities

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your Androidmanifest.xml file `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

**Example**:-

```
<activity
            android:name=".Registration_Screen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
```