# How to stop keyboard popping up in EditText when activity gets opened?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `MainActivity`, there is `EditText` and `PinView` for username and password. When I am opening `MainActivity` keyboard is popping up automatically.

How to prevent it?

In `activit_main.xml`

```
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmailLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lblLogin">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText_mobile"
                        style="@style/lato_regular"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbarHeight"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_bottom_line"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:hint="@string/mobileNumber"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_with_4dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/text_hint_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
        <activity
        android:name=".module.activity.signin.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

        <!-- First activity -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I also tried:

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText_mobile.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Have you check this : `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: yes, but didn't work @NileshRathod

Comment: Please also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710556/7666442

Comment: add android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to parent layout of edit text.

Comment: Hope this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295926/1318946

Comment: @PrashantSable didn't work

Comment: @PratikButani didn't work

Comment: Can you post full activity code?

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/> just use the 2nd attribute in desired activity

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and it is working totally fine. It is not showing keyword until i am clicking on it..
Even you should try..

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="16dp">

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/username"
          style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:drawableStart="@drawable/email_login"
          android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_login"
          android:drawablePadding="12dp"
          android:hint="@string/usernameedit"
          android:imeOptions="actionNext"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:maxLength="32"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:padding="13dp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/tertiary_text_dark"
          android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

     <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/username"
          android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
          android:background="#f9d7db" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines in the ***Root View*** in your XML layout

i.e. ***Root View*** Could be ContraintLayout or any other layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to the parent of the `EditText`

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Also you can use

```
windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

in the Activity Manifest @Makarand